# sitefinity view cshtml accordion list

Tags: sitefinity

I am returning a list object within a list object and wanted to have the sub list in accordion list. Do I need to do this in JS or jquery? Or is this something within sitefinity controls that will be faster and better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like this

https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/RandomSiteControlsMVC/blob/master/RandomSiteControlsMVC/MVC/Views/DocumentTree/Simple.cshtml

(Try here https://rscdemo.sitefinitysteve.com/components/document-treelist)

If you have bootstrap on there, just add the collapse attributes to your elements

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Comment: the bootstrap is great, can I use a variable in the href `<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">` like something like this <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@string.Format("#collapseExample_{0},id)

Comment: No, if it's because you're needing unique names, my view handles that... but there's methods and stuff too in the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#methods